# build When Case query in for loop django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

i try build `queryset` for update data with `When Case`. It only can build after one `for` loop with dynamic param.

Example i have model `Employee`:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    account_type = models.TextField(blank=True,  null=True)
```

i want update it like this, if id = 1 then value = 1, if value = 2 then value = 2

```
Employee.objects.update(
     account_type=Case(
         When(id=1,
              then=Value("1")),
        When(id=2,
              then=Value("2")),
     ),
 )
```

but i want `id` is dynamic, so i cant build static queryset. I want build `Case` in one `for loop`.
My ideal like this:

```
final_case = None
for one_id in list_id:
   final_case += Case(When(id=one_id, then=Value(one_id)))
```

I want build `final_case` and update only like

```
Employee.objects.update(account_type=final_case)
```

Anybody know how to do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create only the `When`s in loop and put them inside a single `Case`.

```
whens = [When(id=id, then=Value(str(id))) for id in ids] # make a list

Employee.objects.update(
    account_type=Case(
        *whens # unpack the list
    ),
)
```

Comment: its only example. My purpose is how to build `Case ` in for loop with dynamic param

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: You Sir, are a saint! :)